# Check if Logged In via ssh or su

Tags: linux, ssh, login, su

Let's say I'm called to a workstation and I face a console and I want to know if the current user logged in via `ssh` or `su`. How can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if you're logged in via `ssh` by looking for environment variables `SSH_CLIENT`, `SSH_TTY` and `SSH_CONNECTION`:

```
$ env | grep SSH
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.0.2 2245 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.0.2 2245 192.168.0.3 22
```